# Conditional Formatting if any cell in row contains text

Tags: excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have this formula which adds a border to a row if a certain cell in that row contains any text:

```
=$C5<>""
```

I want to change the formula to not just look at column C, but at the entire row in the table (which is A:I), i.e. if any text exists at all in that row, it must apply the formatting.

Can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this formula

`=COUNTA($A5:$I5)>0`

`COUNTA` counts non-blank cells so if there is any text in that range COUNTA will be > 0 and trigger the conditional formatting

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I've tested it and It works for me. You need to change the "**Sheet1**" name with your sheet's name. Currently the macro is set to row 100. Check the values for **i = 1 to 100**

```
Sub FormatCells()
Dim Wks As Worksheet: Set Wks = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 100 ' set the max no of Rows
LookupRange = Wks.Rows(i)
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Wks.Rows(i)) <> 0 Then
        With Wks.Rows(i).Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
             Wks.Rows(i).Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        End With
        With Wks.Rows(i).Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        With Wks.Rows(i).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        With Wks.Rows(i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        With Wks.Rows(i).Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Is there any way to do this without a macro? This is a file shared daily between myself and novice excel users. Would prefer to keep thing simple. The macro does work well though.

Comment: I can't see how this would be done without a macro.
As a workaround I would: 1.) **make the macro private** (i.e. private sub ...) 2.) **add an object** (aka. button) in a separate sheet (hidden if needed) and **assign the macro to it**. 3). **run the macro with a single click**, without interfering with the data ?

Comment: @user2725402 - you should be able to achieve this with a simple change to the existing formula - see my answer

Comment: yup, :) :) :) it seams I got the question all wrong to start with. Simple questions demand simple answers.